# Introducing constraints in FrobeniusSolve

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have a knapsack problem. Say I have N possible items $x_i$. I would like to know:

$ \sum_{i=0}^{2} c_i x_i = W$

With the following constraint:

$c_i=3 \lor 4$

As an example suppose the set $x_i=1,\ldots,6000$ and $W=24000$.
How can I use FrobeniusSolve and apply this constraint to $c_i$ efficiently?

Comment: Have you tried reformulating as an LP problem?

Comment: Not really. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Would KnapsackSolve help, it is new in ver. 11?

Comment: Nice! I haven't noticed this function! @bobbym

Comment: @bobbym the problem with KnapsackSolve is that it solves inequalities, not equations.